# Why the $\lim_{x\to\infty} e^{x\sin(x)}$ doesnt exist? Can I have the proof?

Tags: calculus

proof that the $\mathop{\lim}\limits_{x \to \infty}e^{x\sin(x)}$ dosn't exist? Why the limit x to infinity $e^{x\sin(x)}$ doesn't exist? can i have the proof?

Comment: **Why** and the proof are related, but not the same. If you *imagine* $e^x\sin x$ for large $x$, you can see it will oscillate wildly between very large positive $x$ and very large negative $x$. Sure not settling down.

Comment: what have u tried?

Answer (score 6):

**Hint**

Compare $$\lim_{n\to\infty }f(a_n)\quad\text{and}\quad\lim_{n\to\infty }f(b_n)$$ when $$a_n=2\pi n\quad\text{and}\quad b_n=\frac{\pi}{2}+2\pi n.$$

Answer (score 0):

Just plot it and see...

Another illustration: make sequences of well chosen {$x_i$} so that each have a well defined but different limit. E.g.: $x_k= k\pi$, $x_k= \frac \pi 2+2k\pi$, $x_k=  -\frac \pi 2+2k\pi$...

Answer (score 0):

When in doubt, use the definition: if $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} e^{x \sin x} = \ell$ for some $\ell \in \mathbb{R}$, then for all $\varepsilon > 0$ there is an $N$ such that $|e^{x \sin x} - \ell| < \varepsilon$ whenever $x > N$. Thus (for concreteness), there is an $N$ such that $|e^{x \sin x} - \ell| < 1$ whenever $x > N$. Now find finitely many values of $x > N$ such that $|e^{x \sin x} - \ell| \geq 1$. If you get stuck, try determining the conditions under which $e^{x \sin x} = e^x$.